# Does Java have a limit on the class name length?

Tags: java, name-length

This question came up in Spring class, which has some rather long class names.  Is there a limit in the language for class name lengths?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html#3.8) states that identifiers are unlimited in length.

In practice though, the filesystem will limit the length of the resulting file name.

Comment: The Java VM Specification states that any constant string is restricted to 65535 bytes: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#88659

Comment: This is from the second edition ( same as Jon's answer ) . There is no such reference in the third edition.

Comment: current link is broken

Answer (score 33):

65535 characters I believe.  From the Java virtual machine specification:

> The length of field and method names,
>   field and method descriptors, and
>   other constant string values is
>   **limited to 65535** characters by the
>   16-bit unsigned length item of the
>   CONSTANT_Utf8_info structure (§4.4.7).
>   Note that the limit is on the number
>   of bytes in the encoding and not on
>   the number of encoded characters.
>   UTF-8 encodes some characters using
>   two or three bytes. Thus, strings
>   incorporating multibyte characters are
>   further constrained.

here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se6/html/ClassFile.doc.html#88659

Comment: Do you have a such a reference for the third edition? I'm unable to find one.

Comment: 65535 is a limitation of the JVM not the language itself

Comment: I couldn't find the correct part in the third edition of the JLS.  can anybody provide any further information?

Comment: Its the last point of the VM Specification chapter 4.10: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#88659

Comment: For Java 8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.7

Answer (score 3):

With JDK 1.5, the practical limit for class names on Windows XP with 255 -- longer names gave errors in the file system.  This was the full name (directory+package+class).

I have not tried JDK 1.6 on Vista or windows 7, hopefully Sun fixed it to be the NTFS limit of 8000 or so.

Comment: anyone know the answer to JDK 1,6+ ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Java doesn't impose any limit on the class name. But if you interfacing with other systems (e.g. JNI) its better to be on the safe side.

Comment: That's called **undefined behavior**, and bad part of any specs ))