# Is there restriction about Java package name length?

Tags: java

Is there a restriction for the name length of a Java package name?

Like package com.abc.xxx.xxxx.xxxx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1039045/490961

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Java have a limit on the class name length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039029/does-java-have-a-limit-on-the-class-name-length)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In class files there is a practical limit imposed by the fact that the full qualified class name is stored as a (modified) UFT-8 sequence which can have a maximum length of 65535 bytes as the length is store as an unsigned short.

Storing the signature of a *Generic* class might require an even shorter package name. And it will be even more limited if you try to create a method taking the type as a parameter multiple times as the signature will contain the qualified type name for every parameter and the return type in a single sequence, but it is still limited to 65535 UTF-8 bytes in total.

Comment: What is a *"Generic class"*? Is it a generic class (not a proper noun)? Is it literal? Or related to [generics in Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)? Or something else? (Respond by editing your answer, not here in comments.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Why should a clarification be needed when there is only one kind of generic classes? Or what other generic classes do you know? I will improve the answer when you tell me, which aspect was confusing or misleading.

Comment: @Holger I think they were confused about the fact that you put *Generic* in italics.

Comment: @DjSushi that would be strange, as when you look at the edit history you’ll see that *they* added the italics style to the word.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Java language specification ([3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)):

> *"An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, the first of which must be a Java letter."*

However, as @Holger points out, the JVM specification places an upper limit of 2^16 - 1 on string values that can be represented in a classfile constant pool. (See JVM spec [4.4.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.7))

Package names are part of fully qualified class names, and the latter are represented as classfile constant pool entries.  So, the practical upper limit is on the length of the fully-qualified classname, not just the package name.

Hypothetically, if someone were to create a Java implementation that didn't use the standard classfile format, there is another limit ... the length of a Java `String`, which is 2^31 - 1 characters.  (Note that the maximum length of a `String` is not specified in the JLS.  It is the Java class libraries and the javadocs that specify this.)

However, the reality is that these implementation limits are so large that they should not present practical concerns.