# Do any compilers for the JVM use the "wide" goto?

Tags: java, jvm, goto

I figure most of you know that `goto` is a reserved keyword in the Java language but is not actually used. And you probably also know that `goto` is a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) opcode. I reckon all the sophisticated control flow structures of Java, Scala and Kotlin are, at the JVM level, implemented using some combination of `goto` and `ifeq`, `ifle`, `iflt`, etc.

Looking at the JVM spec https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.goto_w I see there's also a `goto_w` opcode. Whereas `goto` takes a 2-byte branch offset, `goto_w` takes a 4-byte branch offset. The spec states that

> Although the *goto_w* instruction takes a 4-byte branch offset, other factors limit the size of a method to 65535 bytes (§4.11). This limit may be raised in a future release of the Java Virtual Machine.

It sounds to me like `goto_w` is future-proofing, like some of the other `*_w` opcodes. But it also occurs to me that maybe `goto_w` could be used with the two more significant bytes zeroed out and the two less significant bytes the same as for `goto`, with adjustments as needed.

For example, given this Java Switch-Case (or Scala Match-Case):

```
     12: lookupswitch  {
                112785: 48 // case "red"
               3027034: 76 // case "green"
              98619139: 62 // case "blue"
               default: 87
          }
      48: aload_2
      49: ldc           #17                 // String red
      51: invokevirtual #18
            // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      54: ifeq          87
      57: iconst_0
      58: istore_3
      59: goto          87
      62: aload_2
      63: ldc           #19                 // String green
      65: invokevirtual #18
            // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      68: ifeq          87
      71: iconst_1
      72: istore_3
      73: goto          87
      76: aload_2
      77: ldc           #20                 // String blue
      79: invokevirtual #18 
      // etc.
```

we could rewrite it as

```
     12: lookupswitch  { 
                112785: 48
               3027034: 78
              98619139: 64
               default: 91
          }
      48: aload_2
      49: ldc           #17                 // String red
      51: invokevirtual #18
            // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      54: ifeq          91 // 00 5B
      57: iconst_0
      58: istore_3
      59: goto_w        91 // 00 00 00 5B
      64: aload_2
      65: ldc           #19                 // String green
      67: invokevirtual #18
            // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      70: ifeq          91
      73: iconst_1
      74: istore_3
      75: goto_w          91
      79: aload_2
      81: ldc           #20                 // String blue
      83: invokevirtual #18 
      // etc.
```

I haven't actually tried this, since I've probably made a mistake changing the "line numbers" to accommodate the `goto_w`s. But since it's in the spec, it should be possible to do it.

My question is whether there is a reason a compiler or other generator of bytecode might use `goto_w` with the current 65535 limit other than to show that it can be done?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The size of the method code can be as large as 64K.

The branch offset of the short `goto` is a signed 16-bit integer: from -32768 to 32767.

So, the short offset is not enough to make a jump from the beginning of 65K method to the end.

Even `javac` sometimes emits `goto_w`. Here is an example:

```
public class WideGoto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000_000; ) {
            i += 123456;
            // ... repeat 10K times ...
        }
    }
}
```

Decompiling with `javap -c`:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: istore_1
       2: iload_1
       3: ldc           #2
       5: if_icmplt     13
       8: goto_w        50018     // <<< Here it is! A jump to the end of the loop
          ...
```

Comment: `// ... repeat 10K times ...` That compiles? I know there is a limit to the size of a single source class...  but I don't know what it precisely is (code generation is the only time I've seen something actually hit it).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It does. As long as the bytecode size of the method does not exceed 65535, and the constant pool length is also less than 65535.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. 64k ought to be enough for anyone I guess. ;)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - *Tips hat at reference.*

Answer (score 36):

There is no reason to use `goto_w` when the branch fits into a `goto`. But you seem to have missed that the branches are *relative*, using a signed offset, as a branch can also go backward.

You don’t notice it when looking at the output of a tool like `javap`, as it calculates the resulting absolute target address before printing.

So `goto`’s range of `-327678 … +32767‬` is not always enough to address each possible target location in the `0 … +65535` range.

For example, the following method will have a `goto_w` instruction at the beginning:

```
public static void methodWithLargeJump(int i) {
    for(; i == 0;) {
        try {x();} finally { switch(i){ case 1: try {x();} finally { switch(i){ case 1: 
        try {x();} finally { switch(i){ case 1: try {x();} finally { switch(i){ case 1: 
        try {x();} finally { switch(i){ case 1: try {x();} finally { switch(i){ case 1: 
        try {x();} finally { switch(i){ case 1: try {x();} finally { switch(i){ case 1: 
        try {x();} finally { switch(i){ case 1: try {x();} finally { switch(i){ case 1: 
        } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } } 
    }
}
static void x() {}
```

[Demo on Ideone](https://ideone.com/Hkuani)

```
Compiled from "Main.java"
class LargeJump {
  public static void methodWithLargeJump(int);
    Code:
       0: iload_0
       1: ifeq          9
       4: goto_w        57567
…
```

Comment: Wow, amazing. My biggest Java project, with a few packages and a few dozen classes between them, compiles to almost 200KB. But your `Main` with `methodWithLargeJump()` compiles to almost 400KB.

Comment: That demonstrates how much Java is optimized for the common case...

Comment: How did you discover that abuse of jump tables? Machine generated code?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I only had to recall that `finally` blocks get duplicated for normal and exceptional flow (mandatory since Java 6). So nesting ten of them implies ×2¹⁰, then, switch always has a default target, so together with the iload, it needs ten bytes plus padding. I also added a nontrivial statement in each branch to prevent optimizations. Exploiting limits is a recurring topic, [nested expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31112260), [lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40866991), [fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48022050), [constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53742619)…

Comment: Interestingly, nested expressions and lots of constructors also hit compiler implementation limitations, not only bytecode limits. There also was a Q&A about [max class file size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42294998/2711488) (perhaps I unconsciously remembered Tagir's answer when writing this answer). Finally [max package name length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22554415/2711488) and, on the JVM side, [max nested synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54909060/2711488). Seems, people keep staying curious.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that in some compilers (tried in 1.6.0 and 11.0.7), if a method is large enough the ever need goto_w, it uses **exclusively** goto_w.  Even when it has very local jumps, it still uses goto_w.

Comment: Why might that be? Is it something to do with instruction caching?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica  Probably just ease of implementation.