# Is there any way to perform a lossless conversion from a String to a java class name?

Tags: java, decode, encode

I want to be able to encode any string into a valid java class name and then decode that class name back into the provided string. I want to be able to do this is a lossless manner, i.e., no two strings can be encoded to the same java class name.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can two equal strings be converted to equal class names?

What is the purpose of this?

What do you mean by lossless?

Comment: @SamuelFrench Yes because they are the same strings. Also, if you don't know what lossless is, I don't think you're fit to answer this question.

Comment: You are (probably) looking for a bidirectional map. See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783020/bidirectional-map

Also, lossless implies compression which you don't specify at all and it is most certainly not needed here.

Comment: @mascoj Lossless is applicable here. For example, an encoding/decoding algorithm where I just use the ascii value of every character would obviously be lossy not lossless.  I need a lossless algorithm.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me. Why a class name? Why a Java class name? Can it include a package? If so, why? If not, why not?

Comment: @EJP You don't need to know why a class name. That's not part of the question. My question is very clear, these are my requirements.

Comment: @Ogen What?  I don't think you understand what lossless means..... Lossless is only valid when talking about compression, if you have a 1-to-1 mapping then you can't have loss so talking about it is pointless. If you are talking about an encoding that encodes any string to a java class name via lossless compression, then no it doesn't exist based on David's answer.

Comment: @mascoj okie dokie

Comment: And the answer is very clear too.  Given the precise statement of requirements you have given - No it is not possible.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this is clearly no.  There are only a finite number of possible Java strings, and not all of them are valid class names.  Therefore, you're asking for a bijection between two sets of unequal cardinalities - which naturally doesn't exist.

Comment: @Slaks appears to disagree

Comment: That's HIS problem, not mine.  I have given you a mathematically valid proof that the answer is "no".  There's no need for me to ALSO point out the flaw in @SLaks' answer.  In any case, his answer may or may not be "good enough" for your purposes - but that's something that I am unable to tell.

Comment: I am still struggling to understand your answer. For example, if we take the binary system which is based on the set {0, 1} with cardinality 2. Any word made from the set of letters with cardinality 26 can be uniquely represented in binary because the 0 and 1 can be used any number of times. Isn't this a contradiction to your answer? Because now we have two sets, with differing cardinalities, where we have a bijection between them no?

Comment: There is a limit on the length of a String in Java, so there are plenty of Strings that are valid, but will become "too long" if you convert them to binary.  So no, your example is not a counterexample to my proof.

Comment: Ah, I was confused, perhaps you should make it clear that there is a length limit on Java strings in your answer?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1179983

Comment: Yes, I realised that instantly and deleted the comment. Sorry about that. But I'd still suggest making it clear that there is a tenth limit in your answer.

Comment: @SLaks' answer is a very good answer that will probably be useful to you.  The flaw in it is that if you have a very long string - close to the maximum possible length - with a few characters that need to be escaped, then the act of escaping them may make the resulting string too long.  If you're not dealing with very long strings, this may not be an issue for you.  So the answer is _technically_ wrong, but _probably_ useful, which is why I haven't downvoted it.

Comment: In fact, the practical limit would be 65535 character ... or less ... strings.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1039066/139985

Answer (score 4):

This is certainly possible.

In any situation where you need to convert arbitrary strings to use a limited set of characters, you simply need to invent an escape sequence.

For example, pick `_` as your escape character, then replace any invalid character, or any underscore, in the source string with an underscore followed by 8 hex digits of the character's Unicode codepoint.

Comment: Ok but what about the situation with the two following inputs: `my$String` being converted into `my_12345678String`. What happens when I try to encode another input called `my_12345678String`? Won't I get the same encoded value
?

Comment: That's why you also need to encode the underscores.

Comment: So then what's the point of converting invalid characters to underscores in the first place if you're just going to encode them? On the contrary, wouldn't converting them all to underscores be a bad thing because all invalid characters will be encoded to the same thing?

Comment: No; I mean encode underscores that appear in the source string, to avoid exactly that problem.

Comment: So this is a two step solution? 1. Encode underscores to their unicode representation. 2. Replace any invalid characters with an underscore and their unicode representation. Am I correct in saying this?

Comment: Just count underscore as an invalid character and you have only 1 step.

Comment: What if my input strings contains 8 hex digits. Won't that mess up the decoding stage?

Comment: That's why you need to add an underscore, just like other invalid characters.

Comment: But digits are allowed in java class names. So that means I may as well convert every single character into it's unicode code point.

Comment: The flaw in this approach is that it only works if the >>encoded<< string is 65535 characters or less.  (This link explains that there is an implementation limit on the length of class names if you are using a spec compliant JVM - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1039066/139985)  Thus, it will not work for >>arbitrary<< strings.